# Representing infinity with python and IPython widgets

Tags: python, python-3.x

I´m exploring the interact function (ipywidgets.interact) in jupyter notebook, and i wondered if there was a way to make slides 'go' to infinity, in the sense that i don´t especify a maximum or minimum value.
for example the fuction:

```
 def func(x):
     return 1/x
```

when I run

```
interact(func, x = (1,10,0.1))
```

¿is there a way to let the slider 'go to infinity' and show that the limit is 0?

Comment: Have you tried `import math` and then using `math.inf`?

Comment: @kaya3 unfortunately that will have the same issue as if you tried `float('inf')` it will return the error `OverflowError: cannot convert float infinity to integer` since the code will try to convert the float to an int.

Comment: However i would ask the question of why would you want to go to infinity, remember that the slider will have to represent your range of numbers and the larger the range that harder it will be to plot small increments. if you truly want an astronomical size then import sys and try with `interact(func, x = (1,sys.maxsize,0.1))` but as you will see its pretty unusable

Comment: well I was just wondering, for example if i wanted to represent that for larger and larger x, 1/x goes to 0, it would be nice to have that kind of option